# Call custom action in WIX on change of value in Combox

Tags: combobox, installation, wix, wix3.5

Am stuck with combo box and custom action in WIX installer.

I have a combo box(drop down) containing few values. I want to show some text on the screen (unique for each item in dropdown) when the user selects a value from this drop down.

In .Net we can do this easily as we have different events pre-defined. But in WIX I don't see any such event.

Has someone faced the same problem? Or can guide me on how can I get it done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Windows Installer (the underlying technology) doesn't let you do so. Literally, it doesn't publish any event when the combobox (dropdown) value changes. You'll have to add a button, for instance, for user to click when he/she changed the value in the combobox...

Alternatively, you can switch to the EmbeddedUI technique ([WiX element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_embeddedui.htm) and [MSI table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb736317.aspx)), but it is much more advanced...

UPDATE: a sample of using button click to update the text.

```
<UI>
  ...
  <ComboBox Property="WIX_VERSIONS">
    <ListItem Value="Windows Installer XML 3.0" />
    <ListItem Value="Windows Installer XML 3.5" />
    <ListItem Value="Windows Installer XML 3.6" />
  </ComboBox>
  ...
  <Dialog Id="MyCustomDlg">
    ...
      <Control Id="ComboBoxMain" Type="ComboBox" X="10" Y="60" Width="300" Height="17" Property="WIX_VERSIONS" />
      <Control Id="ButtonMain" Type="PushButton" X="320" Y="60" Width="40" Height="17" Text="Show">
        <Publish Property="COMBOVALUEFORMATTED" Value="You've chosen the [WIX_VERSIONS] version of the toolset" />
      </Control>
      <Control Id="LabelMain" Type="Text" X="10" Y="80" Width="360" Height="17" Property="COMBOVALUEFORMATTED" Text="[COMBOVALUEFORMATTED]" />
    ...
  </Dialog>
</UI>
```

PushButton can publish more events, for instance, DoAction, which is used to run a custom action on button click. This might be more relevant in your case.

Comment: can you please provide me an example for same?

Comment: this i know, but using some external tool or something else can't I achieve wat i exactly want?

Comment: Yes, you can. Option 1: create a custom application which will handle all the wizard logic itself, and call the msiexec with your package at the very end, when you gathered all the information from the user/system. Option 2: use EmbeddedUI technique I mentioned above (this is supported from MSI 4.5 and higher, and requires you to create a special DLL to handle all the UI logic itself). Both options have their benefits and drawbacks, both are the workarounds to the Windows Installer UI limitations.

Comment: The sample of EmbeddedUI: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc542588.aspx. Pay attention to the comments as well...

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this in WiX. You just need to manufacture your own changed event.

We compare our DoAction condition to another property which will hold the previous state of the Combobox - VIRTUALWEBSITEOLD

Execute a custom action in the ComboBox when old does not equal new:

```
    <Control Id="WebSite" Type="ComboBox" Width="180" Height="18" X="120" Y="48" ComboList="no" Property="VIRTUALWEBSITE">
       <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="LansaInitVirtualFolders"><![CDATA[VIRTUALWEBSITE <> VIRTUALWEBSITEOLD]]></Publish>
    </Control>
```

Then the Custom Action performs the same comparison as the DoAction (probably not required) and then saves the Combobox value in the OLD property.

```
  Tstring wszWebsite = ReadProperty( _T( "VIRTUALWEBSITE") );
  Tstring wszWebsiteOld = ReadProperty( _T ( "VIRTUALWEBSITEOLD" ) );

  // If unchanged ignore request
  if ( wszWebsite == wszWebsiteOld ) return true ;

 [Do Some stuff]

  // Set the saved state of the combobox so we don't get called again until it changes
  if ( nResult == ERROR_SUCCESS || nResult == ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
  {
     WriteProperty( _T("VIRTUALWEBSITEOLD" ), wszWebsite.c_str () );
  }
```

(Note: Also need to use Twin Dialog Pattern if updating, say, a listbox control. If your control doesn't update but Next and Back DOES update it, then Twin Dialog Pattern will ensure it updates)